# Hidden Service as client or relay?

Tags: onion-services, attacks

Take a look, what is the difference between Tor-Browser in onion encrypted traffic and Apache service responses in onion encrypted traffic?

Tor-Browser: sent 1% / receive 99%. 
It is simply,

- Request: "connect to google.com, Get /" = 1kb
- Response: "!doctype html html itemscope="... blablabla" = 16kb

Apache as Hidden Service: sent 99% / receive 1%. Vice-verse Picture!

Is my hidden service hidden against simple attack Weighting-Request/Response?

Most of humans suggest me to use client mode for hidden-service and do not touch Relay for such task. Is it still true?

Comment: If you run client mode, your traffic will dipend by what you do (such uploading file, visiting sites...) if you run Relay mode some of your traffic will not dipend by what you do, so your server/client will slow down because your bandwidth is limited.

Comment: anyway, there is options to limit bandwidth for relay. Did you hear such `RelayBandwidthRate 100 KB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)`

Comment: Yes, it's true. But take a look at "Step three" https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en . For security reasons I don't suggest you to use TBB for HS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If your Tor is not a relay, your send/receive bandwidth stats will not be public.
You could run 2 Tors. One to host your hidden service(s) and one relay.